# How to create a self resizing grid of buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, grid, tkinter, autoresize

I am trying to create a grid of buttons(in order to achieve the clickable cell effect) with Tkinter.

My main problem is that I cannot make the `grid` and the buttons autoresize and fit the parent window.

For example, when I have a high number of buttons on the grid, instead of shrinking the buttons so that the grid fits inside the window, I get a stretched frame that goes off screen.

The effect that I am looking for is the grid filling all available space, then resizing its cells to fit within that space. I have read at the documentation, but I still cannot figure out how to make it work.

This is the basic code which is my starting point:

```
def __init__(self):
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.grid()

    #some widgets get added in the first 6 rows of the frame's grid          

    #initialize grid
    grid = Frame(frame)  
    grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)

    #example values
    for x in range(60):
        for y in range(30):
            btn = Button(grid)
            btn.grid(column=x, row=y)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to configure the rows and columns to have a **non-zero weight** so that they will take up the extra space:

```
grid.columnconfigure(tuple(range(60)), weight=1)
grid.rowconfigure(tuple(range(30)), weight=1)
```

You also need to configure your buttons so that they will **expand to fill the cell**:

```
btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
```

This has to be done all the way up, so here is a full example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#example values
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = Button(frame)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")

frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(10)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. I am not sure why I did not find the Grid class. I was reading into the geometry managers documentation, but discovered only the .grid method.

Comment: Your example isn't having the buttons expand when you resize it on my system. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit. I tried it on both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Very helpful example.  @Kiril - you can also call columnconfigure from an object reference, e.g. root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Comment: @Vaughn Cato, thanks for this great answer!  Your full example has some extraneous code, so I've posted a cleaned up example in my answer I just posted, and included screenshots.

Comment: syntax for python27 is, sticky='nsew' (not sticky=N+S+E+W)

Comment: @mosh it depends on the version of tk, but yes good point that some people may need to use 'nsew'

Comment: Can you set a default size for the grid when it starts? How would you do that? Sorry it's a side question but kind of related to the creation of the grid. Also what does 'grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)' do in this code? Thanks

Answer (score 45):

[@Vaughn Cato gave an excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591453/4561887). However, he has accidentally included a bunch of extraneous code in his example. Here is a cleaned up and more organized full example doing exactly what his example does.

```
from tkinter import *

#Create & Configure root 
root = Tk()
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

#Create & Configure frame 
frame=Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

#Create a 5x10 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
for row_index in range(5):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)
    for col_index in range(10):
        Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)
        btn = Button(frame) #create a button inside frame 
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)  

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshots:

When it first opens (small):

[image]

After you maximize the window:

[image]

### TODO

1. [ ] 3 Aug. 2023: Update & modernize my example. Some changes occurred to the main answer that I should look at.
2. [ ] 3 Aug. 2023: Remove `from tkinter import *`, and use `import tkinter` instead, as
   it's bad practice to import all. It's better to see explicitly where
   each object comes from by using a module's namespace explicitly.

Comment: I copied and pasted this exact example, and it resized horizontally 'we' but not vertically, 'ns' on OS X 10.13.4 with python 3.6.4. I have no idea why, but your code works on my windows machine just fine. I discovered that if I used the ttk module's Button the resizing works as you demonstrate. So OS X users take note, use the tkinter.ttk.Button instead of the tkinter.Button or this won't work.

Comment: How do i implement this into a programm using multiple classes?

Comment: That works with duplicating the same button XxY times.  What happens when you want to have XxY different buttons in the same grid?  I tried setting the row/col to row_index/col_index on all the buttons, but only one of the buttons is being displayed XxY times.  The variables are not incrementing.

Answer (score 4):

To make the buttons expand when the window is maximized, try to modify the button.grid entry as follows:

```
btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

Answer (score 1):

The grid weight method might not work when you use scrollbar (at least in Mac) , so while using it pack the widget and scrollbar inside a frame and then grid the frame instead.