# Resize scroll for checkbox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, scroll

After several tests and help received, I managed to get the code for a scroll with several checkboxes inside. My current problem is that the scroll is much larger than the space it needs and in general I can't change its size to my liking.
This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class CheckboxList(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.checkbuttons = []
        self.vars = []
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')
        for i in range(20):
            var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text=f"checkbutton #{i}", variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
            cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
            self.checkbuttons.append(cb)
            self.vars.append(var)
        self.frame.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        
    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

root = tk.Tk()
cl = CheckboxList(root, width=20, height=10)
cl.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
root.mainloop()
```

I have made several tests by changing the values of "grid" but I can not. I wish I could have more control over the size.
As you can see from the image, there is a lot of white space left and I would like to be able to change the overall height as well
[image]

EDIT:
Working code:

```
class CheckboxList(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
    super().__init__(master, **kw)
    self.checkbuttons = []
    self.vars = []
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    #self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', bd=0,width=115, highlightthickness=0)
    self.yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')
    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.config(width=e.width, scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))

    for i in range(20):
        var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text=f"checkbutton #{i}", variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.checkbuttons.append(cb)
        self.vars.append(var)
    self.frame.update_idletasks()
   
    self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
    
def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
    self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
```

Comment: Try: `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1); root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1); self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`. For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591453/11106801)

Comment: I think using `pack()` on `cl` is more easier than using `grid()` as you can just call `cl.pack(fill="both", exapnd=1)` is enough.

Comment: @acw1668. Typo expand=1)  not exapnd=1)

Comment: @TheLizzard columnconfigure doesn't seem to work for me but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @acw1668 I can't use pack because all my code is setup with grid

Comment: Are you asking how to get rid of the white space between the end of a checkbutton and the scrollbar to the right? Or are you asking how to get rid of the grey space between the scrollbar and right edge?

Comment: "get rid of the white space between the end of a checkbutton and the scrollbar to the right" this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of `self.canvas` same as `self.frame` whenever `self.frame` is resized via callback of event `<Configure>` on `self.frame`.  Note also that you need to update `scrollregion` of the canvas when the size of `self.frame` is changed.

```py
        ...
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.config(width=e.width, scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        ...
        # scrollregion will be updated via the above event binding on self.frame, so below line is not necessary
        #self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This seems to work fine but only after i've used the wheel and i don't understand why. as soon as I start the white space remains, as soon as I use the wheel it disappears

Comment: I don't have the issue.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I'm using

Comment: @Jake85 You need to call `self.frame.bind(...)` before adding checkboxes.

Comment: Perfect, now it works correctly. A thousand thanks! Can I ask as a last thing that you advise me to make a slight border around the scroll?

Comment: @Jake85 I don't get what you want in your last comment.

Comment: I would like a small border around the scroll. To prevent it from blending into the window background

Comment: @Jake85 Try `cl = CheckboxList(root, bg="white", padx=5, pady=5)`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `width` in line 8.

Change this:

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

to:

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', bd=0,width=115, highlightthickness=0)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Jake85. This is not a practical for every day and not widely used.

Comment: What's the best approach to have a scroll with checkboxes in it then?
I am open to any changes