# serial readline() doesn't work in program

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I want to send commands to an Arduino and I want to get the Answers with serial readline(). That works fine when I try it in the inline console of Python. But when I do it in a script like here:

```
    import serial
    import time

    ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)



   ser.write("T")
   time.sleep(0.5)
   print ser.readline()

  ser.write("5")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()

  ser.write("0")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()

  ser.write("0")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()

  ser.write("0")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()


  ser.write("0")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()


  ser.write("0")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print ser.readline()


  ser.write("R")
  time.sleep(0.5)


  ser.write("M")
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

the program stops at the first readline() function

Comment: serial communication is blocking. In other words, your python code will wait and only resume once Arduino has said something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553543/pyserial-non-blocking-read-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline()` usually waits for string termination character, such as `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`. `write()` in most cases also does require this character. Since your code works from console, add `\n` to the end of strings to send. If `\n` doesn't work, try `\r` or `\r\n`.

```
ser.write("T\n")
time.sleep(0.5)
print ser.readline()
```

Alternatively, you can read lines this way:

```
s = ''
while ser.inWaiting():
    s += ser.read()
print s
```