# PYTHON: Serial read freeze the GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm implementing a GUI with PyQt5 and PyCharm IDE for one of my systems which communicates through a serial interface. When I send an appropriate command, the system starts a data stream with packets defined like the following:

`| 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x02 | [...32 bytes...] | 0x03 |`

The first, the fourth, and the last byte are just markers, the second and the third are control bytes, and the remaining 32 bytes are the information.

When I start the stream, the system receives the command but the GUI freezes. So I started to debug watching the variable which store the incoming values.

The simplified code is

```
def main():
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

main = MainWindow()
main.show()
# app.connect(notifier, SIGNAL('activated(int)'), Update)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(main.Update)
timer.start(2)

app.exec_()

def Update(self):
    if self.read == True:
        self.datain = self.SerPort.Take()
        # if self.datain == None:
        #     pass
        # else:
        self.dataList = list(self.datain)
        self.disp_chan_1.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[0] * 0.000535434481))
        self.disp_chan_2.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[1] * 0.000535694653))
        self.disp_chan_3.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[2] * 0.000537407175))
        self.disp_chan_4.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[3] * 0.000534853598))
        self.disp_chan_5.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[4] * 0.000536425262))
        self.disp_chan_6.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[5] * 0.000536408834))
        self.disp_chan_7.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[6] * 0.000536337893))
        self.disp_chan_8.setText('%f' % (self.dataList[7] * 0.000536237792))
    else:
        pass

def Take(self):
    rxtemp1 = self.ser.read(4)
    rxData = self.ser.read(32)
    rxtemp2 = self.ser.read(1)
    value = struct.unpack('f'*4, rxData)
    return value
```

and the output of the debugger for these variables is

```
rxData = {bytes}b'\xf2\xa4\xe7=\xc0Y\xc4=\xdc\x15\xdc=\xae\xf2\xed=\x9ai;>\xff\xc3\xfe=\xab\x0e\x13>\xebd:A'
rxtemp1 = {bytes}b'\x01\x00\x00\x02'
rxtemp2 = {bytes}b'\x03'
```

It shows that the `rxtemp1` and `rxtemp2` variables are correct (they collect the markers and the control bytes) and so the `rxData` variable which collects the information seems to be correct.

But the GUI freezes immediately and I have to kill the process.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Copy and past the debugger output. A screenshot is undesirable but certainly better than a picture of your physical screen.

Comment: Do the same problems occur when running code *outside* of the IDE/debugger (i.e. in a console or command window)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I changed the image with code

Comment: Probably you are blocking waiting for data from the serial interface. I would try asynchronous I/O - sorry for not being more specific but it is hard to reproduce your setup in order to write a proper answer. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553543/pyserial-non-blocking-read-loop

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes. If I run the application it freezes. For this reason I'm using the debugger.

Comment: I found the error. Thanks to @ekhumoro for making me think to launch the application in the console. PyCharm was set without output message and so I didn't see the error output. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The application freeze because this line

```
value = struct.unpack('f'*4, rxData)
```

In rxData there are 32 bytes but the unpack command above wants 4 group of 4 bytes, 16 in all.
The correct command is

```
value = struct.unpack('f'*8, rxData)
```

I haven't see the the output message error because my PyCharm was set wrong.