# Why is my while True loop stcuk at i = 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my script I have a `while True` loop that constantly checks a mysql database. My problem is, that this while True loop seems to run only once! I added variable `i`, but it's also stuck at 0. Can anyone help me?

```
import mysql.connector
import serial
import threading
import time

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    passwd="",
    database=""
)

cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

getData = "SELECT * FROM log"

ser = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/tty.usbmodem14111"
)


def serial_read():
    while True:
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        return line


def serial_write(mode):
    while serial_read().startswith("OK") == False:
        print(f"Set: {handle_data().mode}")
        ser.write(f"Set: {handle_data().mode}".encode('utf-8'))

    return True


def handle_data():
    modeOld = None
    i = 0

    while True:
        i += 1
        cursor.execute(getData)
        mydb.commit()
        values = cursor.fetchall()

        mode = values[-1][1]

        print(serial_read())

        if mode != modeOld:
            print("{}: {}".format(i, mode))
            serial_write(mode)
            modeOld = mode

            if serial_write(mode) == True:
                print("Mode Set successfully!")


serial_read_thread = threading.Thread(target=serial_read())
handle_data_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_data())

serial_read_thread.start()
handle_data_thread.start()
```

Edit 1: I deleted the try except block

Edit 2: Now I know that it's in the `if mode != modeOld`-block. I just can't find the error there.

Edit 3: I now use threading. It still seems to iterate only once

Comment: Your first `try` block isn't useful. Just initialize `modeOld` and `i` before the loop.

Comment: @chepner Right. I totally forgot about it. (My "P" and "O") buttons dont work well

Comment: `mode = values[-1][1]` Why are you trying to access index -1?

Comment: Make a minimal reproducible example removing all unrelated code.

Comment: @ThomasJohannesmeyer Isn't "-1" the last index of a list? input looks like this `2018-09-01 12:41:31, 0`

Comment: I suspect a problem with your indentation, although I don't see how this loop would *ever* terminate; you don't have any `break` statements.

Comment: Apparently it is. Didn't know about that one! :)

Comment: @chepner I also think that this could be the error, but I just can't find it.

Comment: It sounds like you've updated your code, please update it in the prompt also.

Comment: I think I found something, that could help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553543/pyserial-non-blocking-read-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the threading calls, you are calling the target, remove the parens from the end of the target= assignments  and it will work as expected.

Also, you do not need to call the serial read function in a thread, that is wasting cycles, as the handle data thread already calls serial read to get the data.