# How do I read serial data and perform calculations using the data in parallel, in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, real-time

I'm trying to read serial data streamed to my PC in Python continuously, while another part of the code takes a window of this data and performs calculations simultaneously.

The serial data needs to be saved without interruption, so that it represents a real-time waveform; while also being able to be accessed by the section of the program that performs the calculations.

I've been using pySerial with success and can batch-process the data once it is read and saved, but I need a method of saving the serial data in a non-blocking way for real-time calculation.

Apologies if I've repeated myself , I just want to be clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySerial non-blocking read loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553543/pyserial-non-blocking-read-loop)