# How to catch a character from keyboard

Tags: python, windows

I am working on a python project and I have got the following questions.
How to catch a character in python ? What modules I need to use ? What functions I need to use?

Comment: Read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input

Comment: Use punput https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take a line of input just use:

```
x = input('Your name: ')
y = input()
```

Or (For Python 2)

```
x = raw_input('Your name: ')
y = raw_input()
```

---

For taking just one character from the keyboard you can use `msvcrt.getch()`:

```
import msvcrt

key = msvcrt.getch()

if key == 'a':
    print("You pressed a")
```

Comment: Note that `msvcrt.getch` is only for a console application.