# Pass an argument to a program in terminal that takes input after you start it

Tags: python

I have a program that I am using which takes input in terminal after you start the program. It will not take the input by adding it after the process name. How can I pass it what I want? I know I could use virtual keypresses, but that seems inefficient and non-pythonic, so it will be my last resort.

Below is an example of what I type and get when using the terminal, because I feel that I did not explain as well as I would have liked.

```
user:~ $ program_name
Enter your input here:
```

Comment: @downshift No, he's assing how to pass data to the program's standard input.

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module, with the `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` option.

Comment: This has already been answered I think, try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5405460/2241241

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with the example in your question? When the program says, "Enter your input here:", you would normally type the input. What do you want to do instead?

Comment: @DYZ His question is clear (to me): "How can I pass it what I want?"

Comment: @fbence He's not asking how to read input. He's asking how to provide input to a shell command that he executes from the script.

Comment: oh, sure, yeah, in that case your subprocess solutions seems to be the way to go

Comment: @Barmar If that's what he asks, then he should use shell redirection from a file, as in `program_name < data`.

Comment: @DYZ The question doesn't say anything about a file. He probably wants to provide the input from Python variables.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I believe neither you nor I understand the question well enough to give a qualified answer. Perhaps you are right.

Comment: @DYZ I don't think it's necessary to answer. There are other questions that explain how to give input to a program from Python, just vote to close it as a duplicate.