# How to set unlimited iterations on a specific argument of a given function for Python?

Tags: python

[Sum Of Multiples Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrzaM.png)

This program was made for the Project Euler problem "Multiples of 3 and 5". Although this does solve the problem, I want to further improve on the code. Specifically, make it so that you may input an unlimited number of items, instead of being limited to two base numbers.

Somehow, I figured to use a list, make the function recursive, or use a function within the function.

```
def SumOfMultipleBase2(multiple1 , multiple2 , start , limit):
sum = 0
    for i in range(start , limit):
        if 1%multiple1 == 0 or 1%multiple2==0:
           sum += 1
print('The sum of the multiples of ' , multiple1, ' or' , multiple2 , 'between ', start , ' to ' , limit , ' is ' , sum , '.')
```

Comment: Please, only post code as text and not image. You should look at *args and **kwargs. :)

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: Please explain your exact problem with sample code and expected Output..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read keyboard-input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input)

Comment: @gonczor where have you seen mention of "reading the keyboard" ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's how I understood `so that you may input an unlimited number of items`. if it's not what author intended, then I'm sorry.

Comment: @gonczor the "input" term can be misleading indeed - but it's often used as a synonym to "arguments" or "parameters", and the rest of the sentence made this clearer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers OK, I see. I've retracted my flag.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use '*args' to pass your numbers I think a list or tuple will be okay. The code then could look something like:

```
def som(start, stop, base): ## base is a list of the numbers you want to use as possible base.
  n = 0
  for i in range(start, stop):
    for b in base:
      if i % b == 0: ## if any match is encountered add 1 and break out of the loop.
        n += 1
        break
  print("there are", n, "multiples of any number in", base, " between", start, "and", stop, ".")
```