# How to ask user for new item and add this to list (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am learning python and already know how to add new items to a list by myself with append. I don't know the code to ask the user for a number and add this to the list.

Thanks in advance.

Marloes

Comment: What is it that you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read keyboard-input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
x = list() # Your list
x.append(1) # Appended by you
user = int(input("Enter Number")) #User Input
x.append(user) # Appended user input
print(x)
```

Comment: Accept the answer if u found it useful @Marloes Delgijer so that others could benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
some_List = []      # an empty list

for i in range(3):   # a for-loop  with 3 iteration
    userInp = input("Enter a str to add to the list: ")   # take the inp from user
    some_List.append(userInp)  # append that input to the list

print(some_List)   # print the list
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter a str to add to the list: 1
Enter a str to add to the list: a
Enter a str to add to the list: 2
['1', 'a', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in Python3

```
listname = []
inputdata = input("enter anything : ")
listname.append(inputdata)
print(inputdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt method 'input' to ask for input from the user.

But remember one important thing, that whatever you will receive from that will be of the type str so make sure that you convert it according to your use case.

```
number_list = list()

number = input("Enter Number: ")

# now for your use case since you are dealing with numbers, convert the input into int 
number = int(number)

number_list.append(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
your_list.append(int(input("Enter Number:")))
```

The `append()` adds to the end of `your_list`.
The `input()` requests a number from the user. It will be converted to an integer.

> Note: the code does not checks the user gave you an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['number', 6]  # a list

user_input = input("Type something: ")
my_list.append(user_input)
print(my_list)  # Output: ['number', 6, user_input]
```