# How to get input from the console without blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blocking, discord.py, console-input

I want to make a command to send a message to a text channel or a user,and the message should be input at console,but input() seems to "**block**" the program. Although I had tried threading to figure out this problem,the problem still remain unsolve.How can I do to fix the problem?

easy code like this:

```py
import discord
import typing
from discord.ext import commands

class BasicCmd(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, *, receiver: typing.Union[discord.User, discord.TextChannel]):
        '''
        I want to get input from console
        but input() block the program.
        '''
        content = input('Enter something: ')
        await receiver.send(content)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(BasicCmd(client))
```

If I do it with threading:

```py
import discord
import typing
import threading
from discord.ext import commands

class BasicCmd(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, *, receiver: typing.Union[discord.User, discord.TextChannel]):
        '''
        I want to do this command with threading to figure out  
        this problem,but the problem still remain unsolve.
        '''
        content = threading.Thread(target=input,args=('Enter something: ',)).start()
        await receiver.send(content)
        '''It will  raise an HTTPException(Cannot send an enpty message,and the bot also "block" by "input")'''

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(BasicCmd(client))
```

---

I have modified my program,but the input still block my program.
code(just test):

```py
import discord
import typing
import queue
import threading
from discord.ext import commands

class BasicCmd(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        inputQueue = queue.Queue()

        inputThread = threading.Thread(target=_read_kbd_input, args=(inputQueue,), daemon=True)
        # It still remain "blocking"
        inputThread.start()

        while (True):
            if (inputQueue.qsize() > 0):
                input_str = inputQueue.get()
                print("input_str = {}".format(input_str))
                return

def _read_kbd_input(inputQueue):
    print('Ready for keyboard input:')
    a=True
    while a:
        input_str = input()
        inputQueue.put(input_str)
        a=False
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(BasicCmd(client))
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea do this using the console and you'll need to create an UI for that... But eventually this could help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/

Comment: duplicate with answer on [Non-blocking, multi-threaded example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344690/248390); [`input`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) wait for a newline or EOF

Comment: @bufh Thank for your help,but the problem still remain unsolve. I have edited my post.

Comment: is it good to think about key press listeners instead of using input() blindly?

Comment: @Kris That is a good idea,but if I want to input Chinese or other language.What should I do with the key press listener?

Comment: Could you just send and receive messages in a private channel with your bot instead of using the terminal?

Comment: @Patrick Haugh Yes,I could.But some message can't send in a text channel.For instance,a Emoji from other guild(if you have vip on Discord, it can).If I get comtent from console, I could send a Emoji which is from other guild.

Answer (score -1):

make a new async def for input

```
async def noinput():
  global inputoutput, askinput
  while True:
    if askinput==True
       inputoutput=input('input: ')
       askinput==False
```

then, you have to run it before you run your bot at bottom

```
client.loop.create_task(noinput())
client.run(token)
```

your input asker should be like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
  global askinput, inputoutput
  if message.content.startswith("input"):
    askinput==True
    while askinput==True:
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
    output=inputoutput
    #do something with output
```

example code

```
async def noinput():
  global inputoutput, askinput
  while True:
    if askinput==True
       inputoutput=input('input: ')
       askinput==False

client=discord.Client()
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
  global askinput, inputoutput
  if message.content.lower() == "input":
    askinput==True
    while askinput==True:
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
    message.channel.send(inputoutput)
client.loop.create_task(noinput())
client.run(token)
```

Comment: anyway this code is better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input/53344690#53344690