# Getting " 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'isdigit' " error on my code

Tags: python, python-3.8

with the code I'm trying to accomplish is that I'm asking the user to for a number between 1 and 12 and then display the times table for that number.
The while loop checks if it's not a number or if its less than 1 or more than 12 then it will loop until it input is correct. However I get the error (written on the title)
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
﻿user_input = print('Input number between 1-12: ')


#While loop to keep checking the following conditions
while (not user_input.isdigit()) or (int(user_input < 1) or int(user_input > 12)):
  print("Please input a number between 1-12")
  user_input = print("Input selection >>  ")

#Now convert user_input into an int
user_input = int(user_input)
print('------------------------------------------')
print()
print(f'This is the {user_input} times table')
print()
for i in range(1,13):
  print(f'{i} x {user_input} = {i*user_input}')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read keyboard-input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404068/how-to-read-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_input = input('Input number between 1-12: ')


#While loop to keep checking the following conditions
while (not user_input.isdigit()) or (int(user_input)< 1 or int(user_input) > 12):
```

list of issues:

- you printed instead of `input` to receive input from the user
- you attempted to use `<` on instances of `str` and `int`, instead you should check this outside the `int` conversion to make sure that you trying to use `<` which both operands are `int`

Comment: My fault, was looking at the code several times I didn't catch the print instead of input issue. My bad. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = print('Input number between 1-12:')
```

The above line only print out `Input number between 1-12:`  to the console, it does not ask for the user to input anything. Since the `print()` function displays the string inside it and returns `None`, you get the error that you're getting.

If you want to take user input, then use the `input()` function like,

```
user_input = input("Input number between 1-12: ")
```

The above line will prompt the user to input something while also displaying the text

Comment: I didn't catch the print instead of the input issue. Very stupid of me. Thanks for answering my problem!