# Guessing game doesn't stop when timer runs out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a little US states guessing game where you have 60 seconds to guess as many states as possible and then the script will update your highscore. However, I am having a problem with the timer. it works perfectly except when it runs out, you still get to type in another answer before it exits the code. any ideas?

I am also having a problem where I want the user to be reminded how long they have left... but my 45,30,15,10 and 5 second warnings get in the way of the user's input but one problem at a time I guess.

Any ideas?

```
import time
import threading

# make list of 50 states
states = [x.lower() for x in ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado",
                              "Connecticut", "District ", "of Columbia", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam",
                              "Hawaii",
                              "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana",
                              "Massachusetts",
                              "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi", "Montana",
                              "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico",
                              "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico",
                              "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah",
                              "Virginia",
                              "Virgin Islands", "Vermont", "Washington", "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]]

# start the game
print("Welcome to the US states game!\nYou will have 60 seconds to name as many states as possible\nPress enter to "
      "start!")
input()
print("starting game!")

time_up = False
score = 0


# start counting down from 60
def countdown():
    global time_up
    for seconds in range(10, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)

        # 45, 30, 15, 10, and 5 second warnings
        if seconds in (45, 30, 15, 10, 5):
            print(f"\n{seconds} seconds left!")

    time_up = True


# take answers as inputs
def guessing_game():
    global score
    while not time_up:
        guess = input("Guess a state: ")
        guess = guess.lower()
        if guess in states:
            score += 1
            print(f"Correct! score is now {score}")
        else:
            print(f"{guess} is not a state! try again")

    print(f"Time's up, final score is {score}")


# create threads for countdown timer and guessing game
countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown)
game_thread = threading.Thread(target=guessing_game)

# start both threads
countdown_thread.start()
game_thread.start()

# wait for both threads to finish
countdown_thread.join()
game_thread.join()

# once finished write/rewrite high-score on a txt file

'''
countdown timer gets in the way of answering

game does not finish after countdown, it lets you guess one more time

need function to write/rewrite high score on text file

need to get rid of US overseas territories from list
'''
```

I tried putting another break statement within the while loop but no luck

Comment: `input()` waits for an input, so the `while` in the `guessing_game` will only see the change of `time_up` after the input triggers.

Comment: As @0stone0 said, `input` is blocking. You need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344690/439938

Comment: You should look into asynchronous programming, so that the `input` doesn't block any other code.

Comment: Easiest fix would be to check `time_up` immediately after accepting the input, and if the time is up, disallow that final guess.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
from threading import Timer

def timeout():
    # do your stuff here

t = Timer(number_of_seconds, timeout)
t.start()
```