# Superclass inherits from a subclass. Coursera. Are they crazy?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

[Learn to Program: Crafting Quality Code](https://class.coursera.org/programming2-001/lecture/25)

Screenshot

[image]
This is a video lecture from Coursera Learn to Program Crafting Quality Code Course.
So there is a quiz during the video.

```
class MyInt(int):
    # some code there
```

They gave 4 answers where I need to choose a right one.
I've choose my answers one by one but finally they say that right is absolutely wrong answer.

> int is a subclass of MyInt

This question [Python: How do I make a subclass from a superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607612/python-how-do-i-make-a-subclass-from-a-superclass) gives me absolutely right confirmation that I'am right.

Where is the truth?

Comment: Yes, Coursera is wrong there. Coursera's Python course has *lots* of errors. You need to take this up with Coursera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the quiz, the code as written in the question is declaring that `MyInt` is a *subclass* of `int` (or equivalently: that `int` is the *superclass* of `MyInt`), no the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. I've found another question doubting that Coursera is always correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit from a class, that class is the super-class. In the example `int` is the super (or base) class and `MyInt` is the subclass. They're wrong, just as you suspected. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. # I was not suspecting. :) I'm just boring to watch the videos only to get a certificate. I prefer to learn the core of the language or a technology on their main site.