# Super init vs. parent.__init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

A Python subclass can be initialized with or without a call to `super()`, as shown below

```
class Parent(object):
    ...

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
```

What is the difference between these cases, and is one generally preferable to the other?

Comment: Last one gives you `TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Parent instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`, exactly because the argument is missing.

Comment: `Parent.__init__(self)` I believe you mean I like this method as it is more explicit to me... the MRO is scary black magic

Comment: Yes, sorry I guess I did mean that let me change it.

Comment: Make an [inheritance diamond](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5033903/190597). Then the super calls will invoke different `init` methods than the calls to `Parent.__init__`.

Comment: So when inheriting from a single parent, is there no difference or preferred one to use?

Comment: If you only use single-inheritance, there is no difference.

Comment: Is there a conventional preference?

Comment: They essentially do the same thing because a super call points to the parent class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between super() and calling superclass directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639788/difference-between-super-and-calling-superclass-directly)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The purpose of super is to handle inheritance diamonds.  If the class
inheritance structure uses only single-inheritance, then using super() will
result in the same calls as explicit calls to the "parent" class.

Consider this inheritance diamond:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running A.__init__')
        super(A,self).__init__()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running B.__init__')        
        super(B,self).__init__()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running C.__init__')
        super(C,self).__init__()

class D(B,C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running D.__init__')
        super(D,self).__init__()

foo = D()
```

which prints

```
Running D.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running C.__init__
Running A.__init__
```

while if we change `B` to `B2` and use explicit calls to the parent `__init__`:

```
class B2(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running B.__init__')        
        A.__init__(self) 

class D2(B2,C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running D.__init__')
        super(D2,self).__init__()

bar = D2()
```

then the chain of init calls becomes

```
Running D.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running A.__init__
```

So the call to `C.__init__` is skipped entirely.

---

There is no one preferred option.

If you can guarantee that you do not want to support multiple inheritance then
explicit parent calls are simpler and clearer.

If you wish to support multiple inheritance now or in the future, then you need to use `super()`. But understand that there are [some pitfalls](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) involved with using super, but with [proper use](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) these pitfalls can be avoided.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the second example doesn't actually seem to be calling the explicit class init. It just calls super, like the one above it.

Comment: The 2nd example calls super in first place, but B2 is calling A.__init__ instead super(A,self).__init__(), and that what it means, A is not calling C becuase uses an explicit call.

Answer (score 11):

The primary purpose of `super(Child, self).__init__()` is allow initialization run properly in the case of multiple inheritance with diamond inheritance structures.  If you explicitly call the base class constructors with multiple inheritance some initializers may be called twice.  With single inheritance, there is no functional difference between using super and explicitly invoking the base class `__init__()` method. Note that because all python new-style classes subclass object, multiple inheritance *always* involves diamond inheritance.

super has a lesser benefit of reducing requires changes if you rename or change the base class.

In python 3, the arguments to `super` are optional, so you can just do `super().__init__()`.  Python 2 still requires you to provide the arguments explicitly.