# MRO in python when subclassing with multiple inheritance, using PyQt (QMainWindow)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I recently experienced a `TypeError`, that I didn't understood when I was subclassing a [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) with `PyQt5`.

When creating two classes:

```
class Base (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__(None)

class Base2 (object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        pass
```

and then creating a Subclass of both, without any init arguments:

```
class SubClass( Base, Base2 ):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        Base2.__init__(self, 0,0)
```

I get a TypeError when creating an instance of the subclass:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow    
app = QApplication([])
print( SubClass() )
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(SubClass())
    Base.__init__(self)
    super(Base, self).__init__(None)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

However, when changing the Order for the inheritance `class SubClass( Base2, Base ):` the code will run fine.

---

I read the post in [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/4464653) and [Method Resolution Order](http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) but didn't found an answer on this.

(Also note that this is somewhat PyQt-specific, because I couldn't reproduce the problem with Base-classes entirely based on `object`)

Could someone give a clear explanation for this behaiviour?

Comment: Your implementation is very buggy, so no clear exaplanation is possible. It is always wrong to mix `super` with explict `__init__` calls - all the base-classes must use `super`. You also need to fix the handling of the mismatched signatures -  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36780883/984421) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25014746/984421) to the first question you linked to. Once these problems are eliminated, the order of the base-classes doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It is always wrong to mix `super` with explict `__init__` calls - all the base-classes must use super." - [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro)

I wasn't aware of this - thanks.

Furthermore, based on that, as well as on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36780883/4464653) and [this wordpress article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by Raymond Hettinger, it seems best practise to me to use `**kwargs` to pass all arguments trough the chain of super-calls and filter them part by part for each init:

```
class Base (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

class Base2 (object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class SubClass(Base, Base2): # order can be switched now
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(a=0, b=0, parent=None)
```

this way the MRO gets irrelevant for this example.

---

**Research recommendation**, for other newbies like me:

- *Raymond Hettinger:*

  - [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) *(wordpress)*
  - [Super considered super! - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) *(youtube)*
- [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/4464653) *(best on stackoverflow)*
- [Super init vs. parent.__init__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29173299/4464653)
- [Python super method and calling alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033903/4464653)