# Python What is the best way to initialise a thread?

Tags: python

I have found two different ways to initialize a thread.

I would like to know what is best between:

```py
class Class_name(Thread):

    """docstring for the class"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(Class_name, self).__init__()
```

or

```py
class Class_name(Thread):

    """docstring for the class"""

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
```

If anyone knows which one is best and what differences it makes, it would help me to choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between super() and calling superclass directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639788/difference-between-super-and-calling-superclass-directly)

Comment: One supports cooperative multiple inheritance; the other does not.

Comment: Can you say me which support?