# __subclassess__() function does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I want to get a list of classes in my class. According to this answer [How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name) I should be able to use `cls.__subclasses__`, but this function does not exist.

I tried the answer to question [How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

```py
class X:
  class my_subclass:
    pass

x=X()
x.__subclassess__()

# This reports AttributeError 'X' has no attribute '__subclasses__'
```

I would expect to get a dictionary object or the like. But I just get an error message `AttributeError 'X' has no attribute '__subclasses__'`.

Comment: That's not what a subclass is, by the way.

Comment: The name of the function is [`__subclasses__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__) and it's a `class` method, not an instance method, so you would need to use `type(x).__subclasses__()`. However the list returned will be empty because `my_subclass` is a class _nested_ inside `X`, not a subclass of it.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing 3 things wrong.

**1)** That's not how you make a subclass.

A subclass is not a class *inside* a class, rather it's a *separate* class that you define that *inherits* from a parent/base class. See [Python: How do I make a subclass from a superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1607612/2745495)

```py
class Cake():
    pass

# a subclass of Cake
class Crepe(Cake):
    pass

# a subclass of Cake
class Pound(Cake):
    pass
```

**2)** You have to call `__subclasses__` on the parent class name, not on the instance.

```py
an_instance_of_crepe=Crepe()

an_instance_of_crepe.__subclasses__()
# This will result in "AttributeError: 'Crepe' object has no attribute '__subclasses__'"
# This is what you are getting

Cake.__subclasses__()
# This will work, and printing out the result will give
# [<class '__main__.Crepe'>, <class '__main__.Pound'>]
```

**3)** It's `__subclasses__` (1 '**s**' at the end)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method is

```
__subclasses__
```

You wrote:

```
__subclassess__
```

See the extra 's'?