# Python Class with Class input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am investigating the source code of a package, and noticed that classes are able to call certain methods that aren't defined within the class.

For example:

```
inst = ClassA()
meth = inst.meth1()
"some stuff printing to console"
```

However, `meth1()` is not defined within `ClassA`.  In the ClassA definition, there is an input that references another class:

```
from package.sub.file import ClassB
class ClassA(ClassB):
    ...normal class stuff...
```

From another file:

```
class ClassB:
   ...normal class stuff...
    def meth1(self):
        ...stuff...
```

My main question is how is this possible?  How does `meth1` become a method for `ClassA`?  I am confused as to why passing `ClassB` as an input transfers all the methods associated with `ClassB` to `ClassA`

Comment: This is called inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, inheritance is sort of a main feature of class-based OOP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607612/python-how-do-i-make-a-subclass-from-a-superclass?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How do I make a subclass from a superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607612/python-how-do-i-make-a-subclass-from-a-superclass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inheritance, a common concept in object-oriented programming.

When one class (the child) inherits from another (the parent), an instance of the child is treated exactly the same as an instance of the parent. That means that if a parent defines a method, it is available to instance of its child as well.

---

As to how Python implements inheritance, buckle up :)

When `ClassA` is created, it has an attribute called the method-resolution order (MRO) added to it.

```
>>> ClassA.__mro__
(<class '__main__.ClassA'>, <class '__main__.ClassB'>, <class 'object'>)
```

This is built using `ClassA`, its parent classes, and *their* parent classes, all the way up to `object`, the ultimate base class; and it is used for all sorts of attribute lookups.

A somewhat abridged account:

When you try to call `inst.meth1`, Python goes through the following steps (some steps omitted for clarity and brevity):

1. Does `inst.meth1` exist? No. Start checking the classes in the MRO
2. Does `ClassA.meth1` exist? No, check the next class.
3. Does `ClassB.meth1` exist? Yes.
4. What is `ClassB.meth1`? It's a function; call it with `inst` as the first argument.

Thus (without going into the descriptor protocol in detail), `inst.meth1()` is equivalent to `ClassB.meth1(inst)`.